# How to install lxml when something went wrong in "gcc" and "libxml2"

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

OpenSUSE Leap 42.1, python 2.7.9, pip 8.1.2

I wanna install Tushare, but the terminal told me there was no lxml. Then I use `sudo zypper in libxml2` first,but when I want to install  "lxml" with lxml-3.6.1.tar.gz downloaded from the official website. It returns:

```
    compilation terminated.
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitVXdVTQ.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitVXdVTQ.o
    /tmp/xmlXPathInitVXdVTQ.c:1:26: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: no such files or directory
    #include "libxml/xpath.h"
                            ^
    compilation terminated.

    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've installed 'gcc' before. Then How can I deal with this problem?
And How should I find the keys to such problems in the future?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the development library, most likely called `libxml2-dev` or `libxml2-devel` in order to compile against the required header (`.h`) files.